# Sitefinity Search on dynamic module resulting no url

Tags: sitefinity

I have  use sitefinity search in Sitefinity 6.3 
Problem is that on the search result the items coming from dynamicmodule doesn't have links. that is the dynamicmodule related items doesn't have href on it while other are showing fine

```
<dt class="sfsearchResultTitle"><a id="cphContent_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_resultsList_A1_1">my item data in dynamic module</a></dt>
```

Please let me know what to do with it?

In the Documentation it is mentioned that

Configure search index settings for dynamic modules
If you are searching in dynamic module items or custom fields created for any module, you must set the fields where you want the system to search.
You do this by expanding Advanced and entering the fields where to search, separated by commas.
For example, if you want to search your dynamic content types by Definition, enter Definition.

But it is not clear.

what i check that my fields are mentioned in search fields list by checking
**settings -> advanced ->dynamic modules -> controls - >mydynamic module -> Views -> mydynamicmoduleBackendList ->SearchFields**

My fields are mentioned there automatically

My user control for search has markup as

```
<asp:Repeater ID="resultsList" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <dl class="sfsearchResultsWrp sfsearchReultTitleSnippetUrl">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="search-result">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="font22 bold result-title">
                                <dt class="sfsearchResultTitle"><a id="A1" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("Link")%>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a></dt>
                            </div>
                            <div class="font13">
                                <br>
                                <dd class="sfsearchResultUrl"><a id="A2" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("Link")%>'><%# Eval("Link")%></a></dd>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </dl>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Please let me know what is wrong

P.S. 
in http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/search-functionality somebody also faced this empty url problem but no answer there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Administration -> Search indexes then your search index, you should be able to specify a default page where the custom content type's are published:

[image]

**Edit**

This doesn't seem to show up for me in either a fresh install of 6.3 but you can inspect the page using Chrome Dev tools and remove the display:none on the .sfContentToIndex .sfPublishDescWrp.sfHideInSearch class to have it show up:

[image]

Then click "Change" and select the details page where this custom content type is published.

**Edit #2**

Alright, I found where to enable this in the settings. In the backend go to Administration -> Settings -> Advanced -> Search -> Controls -> SearchBackend -> Views -> SearchBackendEdit -> Sections -> PipeSettingsSectionInbound -> Fields -> InboundSettings. Then check the "Show content location" checkbox. Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben, 
There isn't any option for setting 
Default page where mytype are published

Comment: Thanks Ben.
It's seem to work. Any idea how i can get rid of this requirement of manually removing diplay:none

Comment: You could try editing the backend search index page by going to Administration -> Backend Pages and then use a css widget to override that style.

Comment: Ben I have tried adding a content block in searchindex pages with css 
.sfContentToIndex .sfPublishDescWrp.sfHideInSearch
{
  diplay:block !important;
}
But the actual widget is inside some iframe 
<iframe name="edit" src="/Sitefinity/Dialog/ContentViewEditDialog?ControlDefinitionName=SearchBackend&amp;ViewName=SearchBackendEdit&amp;language=ar" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; top: -10000px;"></iframe>

Comment: Hi Kamran, I updated my answer with another way to show that information by default. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Ben can we select multiple pages for a module? Because we are showing content from the same module on different pages.